# Wiremock how to map a 302 response in JSON for standalone run

Tags: redirect, mapping, wiremock, wiremock-standalone

In wiremock, if you are using it for testing, you can programately return 302 using temporaryRedirect(String destination) with a detination path

```
stubFor(post(urlEqualTo("/firsturl"))
            .willReturn(temporaryRedirect("https://somehost:8080/test/")))
```

My question is: How can I do the same in standalone running mode, using json mapping file

```
 {
        "request": {
           "method": "POST",
           "url": "/api/test"
        },
        "response": {
           "status": 302,
           ????? <- how to return the path?
       }
 }
```

Was not able to find anything about this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to redirect to a separate url, you can use the [WireMock's proxying functionality](http://wiremock.org/docs/proxying/).

It would look something like...

```
 {
        "request": {
           "method": "POST",
           "url": "/api/test"
        },
        "response": {
           "status": 302,
           "proxyBaseUrl": "https://somehost:8080/test/"
       }
 }
```

Comment: Sry, but you are wrong. 302 status code will be ignored and status code + response body + response headers will be taken from https://somehost:8080/test/.

Answer (score 4):

`temporaryRedirect("https://somehost:8080/test/")` is a wrapper around `aResponse().withStatus(302).withHeader(LOCATION, "https://somehost:8080/test/")`
In json configuration it will be:

```json
 {
  "request": {
    "method": "POST",
    "url": "/api/test"
  },
  "response": {
    "status": 302,
    "headers": {
      "Location": "https://somehost:8080/test/"
    }
  }
}
```